# How to return the result of an inner method in cascaded streams

Tags: java, java-stream

How can I reduce the following statements using Java Stream API?

```
String code = "searchcode";
Inner result;
 for (Outer outer : outerList) {
        for (Middle middle : outer.getMiddleList()) {
            Inner inner = middle.getResultForCode(code);
                if (inner != null) {
                   result = inner;
                }
        }
    }
```

I want to get "inner" or "inner.getRelevantThing()"

something like:

```
Optional<Inner> result = outerList.forEach(middle ->
    middle.stream()
    .filter(middle.getResultForCode(code))
    .findFirst());
```

Comment: Something like `outerList.stream().flatMap(outer -> outer.getMiddleList().stream())
 .map(middle -> middle.getResultForCode(code)).filter(Objects::nonNull).findFirst().map(Inner::getRelevantThing).orElse(null)` ?

Answer (score 3):

You can use [`flatMap`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#flatMap-java.util.function.Function-) to flatten nested streams.

```
Optional<Inner> result = outerList.stream()
    .flatMap(outer -> outer.getMiddleList().stream())
    .map(middle -> middle.getResultForCode(code))
    .filter(Objects::nonNull)
    .findAny();
```

(Note that `findAny` will find any matching item, not the last matching item as your code did.)

If you want the "relevant thing", you can apply a mapping to the `Optional<Inner>`.

```
outerList.stream()
    .flatMap(outer -> outer.getMiddleList().stream())
    .map(middle -> middle.getResultForCode(code))
    .filter(Objects::nonNull)
    .findAny()
    .map(Inner::getRelevantThing);
```

Comment: @Jean-François Savard: I think, you are over-interpreting the edit. The loop variant clearly produces exactly one item and it’s unlikely that the erroneous code inserted with the edit reflects the OP’s intentions better than the correct loop code.

Comment: @Holger Actually, re-reading, I think you both are right. Most likely OP used a `foreach` trying to translate directly from his loop code to a stream solution. +1ed.

Comment: For completeness, to really act like OP's code, one should write a reverse pipeline and then findFirst as the loop code does not behave like a simple `findAny`. Something like : `IntStream.range(0, outerList.size() - 1).mapToObj(i -> outerList.get(outerList.size() - 1 - i).getMiddleList()).map(middleList -> IntStream.range(0, middleList.size() - 1).mapToObj(i -> middleList.get(middleList.size() - 1 - i)).map(middle -> middle.getResultForCode(code)).filter(Objects::nonNull).findFirst())` ... But OP's code is most likely flawed.